# Bootstrap Modal from another page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've met some problems when I try to use `Bootstrap Modal` in my code.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://another.page" data-toggle="modal">Another Page</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://another.page" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Another Page</a>
```

I'd like to modal `another.page` to my page, but it doesn't work.

the `another.page` is looks like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myModal" class="tm-modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="tm-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> </button>
        <h6>Modal Heading</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="tm-modal-body">
        <p>One fine body
          <85>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tm-modal-footer">
        <button class="tm-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="tm-btn tm-btn-recommand">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to load the `another.page` as a `<div>` in my code, because there are too many place that I need to use modal.

Did I missed something important?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page). It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the element `iframe`

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src="another.page" />
</div>
```

And maybe you want to style it

```
.modal iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u29Tj/3/

**Just to be clear, that you read the manual, based on your comments:**

Look at the `data-target` attribute of your link: It is an anchor to the `HTML Element` `Modal Window`. You need this for Boostrap to show and hide the window. You should not linking it to your page. You need to link it to your Modal! In the Modal Body you use the Iframe.

```
<!-- trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801446/bootstrap-modal-from-another-page/23801599" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative**

Homework for you:

- Give each link `data-iframemodal` Attribute you want to have a Iframe.
- Set a Clickhandler for each attribute which has `data-iframemodel`:

  - Open a new Modal via JS. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
  - Set Content with iframe and as source you extract from the event the senders href attribute.

Comment: Not realy understand you question?

Comment: The `<div class="tm-modal-body">` is already in `another.page`, why should I use iFrame in the page?

Comment: I understand: How can i include some other page into my first page "Modal Window"? Iframe is the answer. Excuse me, if I missunderstood you. Can you provide more Details about your Problem?

Comment: @Jimmy Have updated my Anwser. Is this, what you mean?

Comment: Can I put the `Modal <div>` in other page or I should put in the same page? because on my website, there are too many difference places that need Modal(iframe). I also found this website: http://modalwithwebpage.blorkmark.com/# which is like what I want, but the example also put the `modal <div>` in the same page.

Comment: Yes, I update your answer, but the link redirect me to `amother.page`, not a popup windows using Modal.

Comment: If you have readed my answer, you would know why it must be on the same page. Please look in the Manual of Bootstrap if you don't believe me. Look also at my alternative (It is your Homework) if you don't want create multiple Modal Window Markups. By the way: You can write the Modal Markup everywhere between `<body></body>` if this is your Problem. Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u29Tj/1/

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that there are almost 100 places that need to Modals. Write all Modals between `<body>` and `</body>` would make the source code ugly.

Comment: Is this possible without using iframe?

Answer (score 7):

Do you want from the page 1 open the page 2 and than open the modal inside this second page? if yes, here is a solution:

At the first page you'll use:

```
<a href="second.html#myModal" class="btn btn-primary"> Open Modal </a>
```

At the second page you'll insert your modal and the follow script:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function remoteModal(idModal) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.modal = $(idModal);

    if (vm.modal.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }

    if (window.location.hash == idModal) {
      openModal();
    }

    var services = {
      open: openModal,
      close: closeModal
    };

    return services;

    // method to open modal
    function openModal() {
      vm.modal.modal('show');
    }

    // method to close modal
    function closeModal() {
      vm.modal.modal('hide');
    }
  }
  Window.prototype.remoteModal = remoteModal;
})();

$(function() {
   window.remoteModal('#myModal');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the element div

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div id="modal-isi-body"></div>
</div>
```

and make script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
            load_page('http://another.page');
        });
    });

    function load_page(url){
        $('#modal-isi-body').load(url,function(){});
    }
</script>
```

and change

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Another Page</a>
```

this is other solution
good luck

Comment: I tried load_page('http://google.com') did not work... any suggestion ? Ada saran lain gan ?