# Bootstrap modal new page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to make a modal where in if I click the button the modal pops up and the content of the modal is from a different page. Please help me.

This is my code

```html
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to know what Javascript? and where exactly should I put it?
I'm using bootstrap v 3.03 by the way.

Comment: I think this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801446/bootstrap-modal-from-another-page will answer your question.

Comment: Hi. it's not working. :( I need a button that if I click it a modal will pop out but the content is from a different page. It's a form.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this is](http://tutsme-webdesign.info/tutorials/modals/update/modal_remote_v31.html) what you're looking for. 
  You need to pay special attention to this line in particular:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="remote.html" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>
```