# html modal in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this to display my modal.

```
<script>
        Mousetrap.bind('j e f f r e y enter', function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show')
        });              
</script>
```

Normally a button is used.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="remote.html" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>
```

Is there any way to get the modal from another html page and call it using javascript?

Comment: maybe you can use ajax to fetch the html and render it in the current dom?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801446/bootstrap-modal-from-another-page

Answer (score 0):

You can send an Ajax request to get the HTML code for modal, then append it to the document.

```
<script>
    var $modal = undefined;
    Mousetrap.bind('j e f f r e y enter', function() {
        if($modal === undefined)
        {
            $.get('path/to/modal.html', function(data)){
                if($modal === undefined)
                {
                      $modal = $(data);
                      $('body').append($modal);
                }
                $modal.modal('show');
            });
            return;
         }
         $modal.modal('show')
    });              
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! tried this but, nothing happens after typing my mousetrap bind